# Dates format changes to mm/dd/yyyy when put to spreadsheet from google apps script

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my simple code:

```
function doPost(request) {
  var deviceId="JHjdkfjak123214";
  var emailId="sample@sample.com";

  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];

  var rowvals=[];
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MMM-yyyy");
  Logger.log(formattedDate);
  rowvals.push(deviceId);
  rowvals.push(emailId);
  rowvals.push(formattedDate);
  sheet.appendRow(rowvals);
}
```

On running this code, the Logger.log shows date like:

```
29-Jul-2014
```

But in spreadsheet it gets entered as 7/29/2014. I have changed the format of the cells using the abc button so that all cells of the date column have format dd-MMM-yyyy.

Now when entered manually, the dates appear in the format dd-MMM-yyyy. But when entered by script, again they change to MM/dd/yyyy. 
Whats the solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to format date using `Utilities.formatDate()` that converts dates to strings.

The spreadsheet tries to be smart and reconverts these strings to dates again but sometimes its not smart enough !

keep date objects as dates and you should get consistent results that work as well for keyboard input ans script output.

EDIT : it shows indeed a complete date value, change code by adding this line after appendRow.

```
  ...
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),3).setNumberFormat('dd MMM yyyy')
}
```

full code below :

```
function doPost(request) {
  var deviceId="JHjdkfjak123214";
  var emailId="sample@sample.com";
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var rowvals=[];
  var formattedDate = new Date();
  Logger.log(formattedDate);
  rowvals.push(deviceId);
  rowvals.push(emailId);
  rowvals.push(formattedDate);
  sheet.appendRow(rowvals);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),3).setNumberFormat('dd MMM yyyy');// add separators if you want or change the format here
}
```

Comment: Can u put the code. I am not getting what you wish to say. Without Utilities.formatDate() or other similar formatting function, how will the date be output in desired format? I simply tried putting new Date() instead of Utilities.formatDate(), but I got this: 7/29/2014 18:47:10